# Converting Access SQL to T-SQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, ms-access-2010, case-statement

I have a created field in an Access database that I am trying to re-create in T-SQL.  I am getting some incorrect results and I think it is how I wrote the code.  Here is the field in Access that is working correctly:

```
MCP Actual: IIf([lever]="MCP",[actual usd]*IIf([split flag]="x",[split percent],1))*[Allocation Value]
```

Here is how I have it coded in SQL:

```
MCPActual =
    CASE
        WHEN pbd.Lever = 'MCP' THEN pbd.ActualUSD * CASE WHEN ou.SplitFlag = 'x' THEN ((pbd.ActualUSD * ou.SplitPercent) * pda.AllocationValue) END
        ELSE ((pbd.ActualUSD * 1) * pda.AllocationValue)
        END
```

Comment: Can anyone provide some help?  I have confirmed that it is an issue with the way I created the MCPActual field in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't got the END and brackets in the correct sequence try

```
CASE
    WHEN pbd.Lever = 'MCP' THEN pbd.ActualUSD * 
    (CASE WHEN ou.SplitFlag = 'x' THEN 
        (pbd.ActualUSD * ou.SplitPercent * pda.AllocationValue ) 
    ELSE 
        (pbd.ActualUSD * pda.AllocationValue) END)
    END
```

You don't need to multiply by 1 unless you are trying to covert a negative / positive value.